# How to plot colored geometric forms and populate them with string from lists

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, bokeh

I have 3 lists with some strings on it:

```
high = ['string1','string2','string3']
med = ['string4','string5','string6']
low = ['string7','string8','string9']
```

I want to make a plot like the one below:

[image]

It can be any geometric form but I want to put inside them the string from the 3 lists:

```
red form gets high list's strings
yellow form gets med list's strings
green form gets low list's string
```

I have no idea where to start if someone can help me with this, i appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how I approached it:**

I have used the [Plotly Library shapes](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/) to create rectangles and text as points on the axis, you can use the same approach on Seaborn and Matplotlib.

You can create the texts labels on the plot the following way:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter( x=[0, 0, 0], 
                          y=[3, 0, -3],
                          text=["red form gets high list's strings",
                                "yellow form gets med list's strings",
                                "green form gets low list's string"], 
                          mode="text",
                          textfont=dict(color="black", size=18,family="Arail",)))
```

Recatangle shapes for corresponding text coordinates can be created as follows:

```
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    line_color="gray", fillcolor="red",
    x0= <Fixed x0 coordinate point>, 
y0= <desired y0 coordinate point>, x1= <Fixed x2 coordinate point>, y1=<Desired y1 coordinate point>)
```

Moreover, I have updated the figure to hide the axis and ticks

**Full code below:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

# Creating scatter trace of text labels
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter( x=[0, 0, 0], 
                          y=[3, 0, -3],
                          text=["red form gets high list's strings",
                                "yellow form gets med list's strings",
                                "green form gets low list's string"], 
                          mode="text",
                          textfont=dict(color="black", size=18,family="Arail",)))

# Update axes properties
fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False,
                 showgrid=False, zeroline=False,)

fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False,
                 showgrid=False, zeroline=False,)

#x co-ordinate points
rect_x0, rect_x1 = -2, 2 


# Add rectangles
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    line_color="gray", fillcolor="red",
    x0= rect_x0, y0=2, x1= rect_x1, y1=4)

fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    line_color="gray", fillcolor="green",
    x0= rect_x0, y0=-1, x1= rect_x1, y1=1)

fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    line_color="gray", fillcolor="yellow",
    x0= rect_x0, y0=-4, x1= rect_x1, y1=-2)

fig.update_shapes(opacity=0.3, xref="x", yref="y")

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, b=100),
                  height=600, width=800,
                  plot_bgcolor="white")

fig.show()
```

**Result**

[image: Result Image]